# Locked package.json files in Docker container using docker-compose

Tags: node.js, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, package.json

I'm using Docker for Mac and Docker Compose for development of a Node.js application and I'm experiencing an error with the **package.json** file being locked.  The specific error after running `npm install --save <package>` within a running container is:

```
npm WARN saveError EBUSY: resource busy or locked, rename
'/Example/package.json.1647356251' -> '/Example/package.json'
```

The simplified package structure is:

```
▾ docker/
    Dockerfile
  docker-compose.yaml
  package.json
```

The **Dockerfile** contains:

```
FROM node:9.5
ENV SOURCE_CODE /Example
COPY package.json $SOURCE_CODE/package.json
RUN npm --prefix $SOURCE_CODE install $SOURCE_CODE
WORKDIR $SOURCE_CODE
```

The **docker-compose.yaml** file contains:

```
version: "3"

services:
  node:
    build:
      context: ./
      dockerfile: ./docker/Dockerfile
    volumes:
      - ./node_modules/:/Example/node_modules/
      - ./package.json:/Example/package.json
```

The **package.json** file contains:

```
{
  "name": "example",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "example",
  "license": "UNLICENSED"
}
```

Running `docker-compose run --entrypoint bash node` to start bash, then running `npm install --save redux` inside the container yields the warning about the **package.json** file being locked, however files are able to be written in the **node_modules** directory on the host. How can I avoid locks on **package.json** file using this structure?

Comment: Later versions of node (16+) seem to not have this problem

Answer (score 2):

I encountered the same issue and I solved this by mounting the folder where **package.json** is located instead of **package.json** itself.

```
version: "3"

services:
  node:
    build:
      context: ./
      dockerfile: ./docker/Dockerfile
    volumes:
      - .:/Example
```

Mounting **package.json** directly as a volume seems to lock the file.

Comment: The problem with this solution is all the files in the current directory are mounted in the container (e.g., `.git`, `.env`, etc.).  I was hoping to avoid mounting everything and instead select only the files required to build/run the container.

Comment: You could move your source code to a /src subfolder: **./src/package.json** & **./src/node_modules** and mount this with docker compose `- ./src:/Example`

Comment: .dockerignore doesn't prevent files from being mounted

Comment: You also can't use a different name in the docker file

Comment: additionally you can do workaround with links - mounting the directory with files are supposed to be bound and then creating links to them in needed places inside container. though it's not always applicable (and i'm not an expert in docker things).

Comment: I agree with @sal17 that mounting the directory is too much.  I've posted an answer that only mounts the file @ https://stackoverflow.com/a/72118909

Answer (score 0):

Like Green Tree suggested, playing with links works. The idea:

1. create an empty folder in the Dockerfile
2. change the owner
3. create empty package*.json file(s) in that folder
4. create links to these files, where you want them in your image
5. create the equivalent folder in your source, place the package*.json
   file(s) in there
6. in docker-compose, link both directories

In you Dockerfile, do something like this:

```
# Create a home dir, give access to 'node' user
ENV HOME [whatever your home is...]
RUN mkdir -p $HOME && \
    chown node:node $HOME
# Switch to user node
USER node
# We'll place our files in npm-package
# Create that folder, place empty place holders in there,
#   and create a link to them
RUN mkdir $HOME/npm-package && \
    touch $HOME/npm-package/package.json && \
    touch $HOME/npm-package/package-lock.json && \
    ln -s $HOME/npm-package/package.json $HOME/package.json && \
    ln -s $HOME/npm-package/package-lock.json $HOME/package-lock.json
```

The temp files are there for two reasons:

- to be able to create a link
- to have the proper write permissions once they get replace by the mounted versions

Then in docker-compose.yml:

```
services:
  your-service-name:
    volumes:
      - npm-package/:/opt/app/npm-package/
```

Works for me (under Linux)

Answer (score 0):

This is a quite an odd config problem, but I eventually cracked the nut.  The idea is to:

1. Volume mount the host's `package-lock.json` to `package-lock-host.json`
2. Run `npm install` in the container to generate new contents
3. Overwrite the host's contents with the container's newly generated contents

```sh
docker-compose run \
  --rm \
  --name 'package_lock_json' \
  -v "$(pwd)/package-lock.json":'/package-lock-host.json' \
  --entrypoint /bin/sh \
  'YOUR_CONTAINER_NAME' \
  -c "npm install --package-lock-only && (cat /package-lock.json > /package-lock-host.json)"
```