# EBUSY: resource busy or locked in Docker when trying to do npm install

Tags: node.js, docker

I keep getting this error when I am trying to install an npm package.

Volumes in docker-compose.yml is set as follows:

```
volumes:
  - "./backend/packages/package.json:/home/node/package.json:delegated"
  - "./backend/packages/package-lock.json:/home/node/package-lock.json:delegated"
  - "./backend/:/home/node/app/"
  - /home/node/node_modules/
```

I want to run installs from inside the container it keeps giving me the following:

```
npm WARN saveError EBUSY: resource busy or locked, rename '/home/node/package.json.2756152664' -> '/home/node/package.json'
npm WARN saveError EBUSY: resource busy or locked, rename '/home/node/package-lock.json.2814803686' -> '/home/node/package-lock.json'
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like npm uses mv to update the package files, but individually mounted files won't let this happen (just tried on a generic file, same symptom).

A solution using a mounted folder and links works for me, as described here:
[Locked package.json files in Docker container using docker-compose](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48960320/locked-package-json-files-in-docker-container-using-docker-compose/58880425#58880425)

Answer (score 2):

I experienced the same issue when trying to do an npm install of a package inside a docker container. Instead of copying binding/mounting individual files from src folder, i mounted/bound the entire directory. The solution that worked for me was:

1. Persist the `node_modules` volume and bind the entire directory
2. Clear the cache
3. Install through docker.

Here is the view of my docker-compose:

```
version: '3.1'
services:
  windaid:
  image: windaid
  build: ../WindAid-Website
  ports:
   - "3001:8000"
  volumes:
   - /myapp/node_modules #Persist after npm install from Dockerfile
   - ../WindAid-Website:/myapp #Binding entire directory

environment:
  - NODE_ENV=development
  - GATSBY_WEBPACK_PUBLICPATH=/
```

and here is a view of my Dockerfile:

```
FROM node:12.14.0-slim
RUN apt update && apt upgrade -y && \
    apt install gcc g++ make python git libc6-dev build-essential libpng-dev \
    libjpeg-dev libvips-dev libvips musl-dev node-gyp pngquant webp -y
 RUN yarn global add gatsby-cli
# The port gatsby runs on
EXPOSE 8000
WORKDIR /myapp
COPY ./package.json /myapp
COPY ./yarn.lock /myapp
RUN yarn install && yarn cache clean
RUN npm cache clean --force
CMD ["gatsby", "develop", "-H", "0.0.0.0" ]
```

Comment: yes, this simply works! I was in doubt about `../projectfolder` reference, but the rule of docker context apply only to dockerfile.
I think that in the first line in `volumes:` of docker-compose file the mount point is missing, I do not know that syntax.

Answer (score 0):

For some reason, removing `:delegated` works, even though I'm using a Mac.

Actually, for some reason, using yarn doesn't give me this issue anymore.